# Symmetries of letter H

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was asked to write down the table of multiplication (composition) for symmetries of letter H.

However, I don't see how it is even closed: take reflection relative to diagonal (connecting two opposite vertices of H) composition reflection relative to the vertial line passing at the midpoint of the horizontal line of H.

If I am not mistaken, this composition should be rotation of H pi/2 radians. However after "doing so" to H, H does not coincide with its former position.

Comment: Reflection relative to the diagonal does not fix the H shape so it is not a symmetry.

Comment: A reflection relative to the diagonal does not send the shape of $H$ to itself.

Comment: A reflection about both diagonals is a symmetry, but double reflections are equivalent to a rotation--in this case a $180^\circ$ rotation about the center.

Comment: Why not just perform diagonal reflection then rotation by $\pi/2$ radians, then you get H back out

Comment: The symmetry group of the letter $\mathscr H$ would be easier

Answer (score 1):

If you label the four extremities of $\textbf{H}$ with $a,b,c,d$ clockwise starting at the upper left, then the four symmetries are

1. $I=(a)(b)(c)(d)$
2. $V=(ab)(cd)$

   $H=(ac)(bd)$

   $R=(bc)(ad)$

From these you should be able to construct the product table.

If you are not familiar with permutations, let us look at $H=(ac)(bd)$. This represents the reflection of the $\textbf{H}$ about the horizontal axis of symmetry which takes $a$ to $c$ and $c$ to $a$ represented by $(ac)$. It also takes $b$ to $d$ and $d$ to $b$ represented by $(bd)$.

Here is an example of how to multiply two permutations.

Let us multiply $V$ and $R$.

$V$ takes $a$ to $b$ and $R$ takes $b$ to $c$ thus $VR$ takes $a$ to $c$.

$V$ takes $c$ to $d$ and $R$ takes $d$ to $a$ thus $VR$ takes $c$ to $a$.

So part of $VR$ is $(ac)$.

Next, $V$ takes $b$ to $a$ and $R$ takes $a$ to $d$, so $VR$ takes $b$ to $d$.

Finally, $V$ takes $d$ to $c$ and $R$ takes $c$ to $b$, so $VR$ takes $d$ to $b$.

So the rest of $VR$ is $(bd)$.

Altogether, then, $VR=(ac)(bd)=H$.

Follow this example to complete the multiplication table, and note that $I$ is the group identity which leaves each permutation unchanged.

Comment: It may help the OP to point out that $I$ does nothing, $V$ is reflection in the vertical centre line, $H$ is reflection in the horizontal centre line (i.e., the crossbar), and $R$ is a rotation through $180°$.